# Using `tsc` give output module a name

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I use this command:

```
tsc --out foo.js values/java-junit/*.ts --module amd
```

or

```
tsc --out foo.js values/java-junit/*.ts --module system
```

and I get

```
define("index", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var CodeGenerator = /** @class */ (function () {
        function CodeGenerator() {
            this.rawCode = '';
            this.styledCode = '';
        }
        // ...
        CodeGenerator.pluginName = 'java-junit';
        return CodeGenerator;
    }());
    exports.CodeGenerator = CodeGenerator;
});
```

or

```
System.register("index", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var CodeGenerator;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            CodeGenerator = /** @class */ (function () {
                function CodeGenerator() {
                    this.rawCode = '';
                    this.styledCode = '';
                }
                 // ...
                CodeGenerator.pluginName = 'java-junit';
                return CodeGenerator;
            }());
            exports_1("CodeGenerator", CodeGenerator);
        }
    };
});
```

**my question is** - is there a way to name the module with a command line option, instead of the module name being "index"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [amd-module directive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) at the top of the containing file to name your module:

```
/// <amd-module name="NamedModule"/>
export function foo() { }
```

Will generate:

```
define("NamedModule", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    function foo() { }
    exports.foo = foo;
});
```